# Как выводить окна?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Допустим есть файлы `index.php` `login.php` `reg.php`

Мне нужно чтобы при нажатие на кнопки `ЛОГИН` \ `РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ` выплывали окна с содержимым `login.php` / `reg.php` Можно ли сделать это **БЕЗ** использования ***JS***? Если нет то пришлите пожалуйста полную подробную инструкцию как это сделать
***Р.S. я знаю что это можно уместить одним только index.php***

Comment: Совершенно верно поняли, нужно делать единую точку входа `index.php`.  Строить роутинг запросов и подгружать контент по переходу на `url` - адрес страницы. С помощью `XMLHttpRequest` можно подгружать контент без перезагрузки. Прочитайте [спецификацию](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xhr/raw-file/tip/Overview.html)  тут и примеры есть.

Comment: Можно ли использовать XMLHttpRequest вместо вебсокетов? Типа на сайт зашли пару пользователей, и один из них что-то добавил, и сделать так чтоб это сразу же увидели другие пользователи, то есть без перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: не знаю, я начинающий прогер

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Не, сделать это не перезагружая страницу, без `JS` невозможно, но я не могу понять, почему вас пугает эта технология(`Ajax`), ей очень просто в пару десятков строк кода, реализовать данную функциональность, более того с помощью `Ajax` вы можете избавить от промежуточных страниц типа `Login`, `Reg`.

Comment: Тогда, пожалуйста, пришлите подробную инструкцию. Просто пока что не знаю JS

Comment: В интернете есть довольно много готовых вариантов, но конечно если вы все таки хотите реально стабильно реализовать такую форму, вам надо подтянуть хотя бы `jQuery`, с ним уже все пойдет легко.